# Converting SQL inner join, group by and order to LINQ

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, linq

I have created an SQL query as follows:

```
SELECT s.FullName, s.[Id], COUNT(t.[User]) AS Records
FROM dbo.AspNetUsers s INNER JOIN dbo.PBBuilds t
ON s.Id = t.[User]
GROUP BY t.[User], s.[FullName], s.[Id]
ORDER BY COUNT(t.[User]) DESC
```

I'm attempting to convert this to a LINQ query, and this is how far i have got:

```
Dim results = From H In context.Users
           Join C In context.PBBuilds On H.Id Equals C.User
           Group By C.User Into
```

Could anyone please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query -- (make changes accordingly though)

```
var results = From U In context.AspNetUsers
       Join P In context.PBBuilds On U.Id Equals P.User
       Group By new { P.User, U.FullName } Into g
       Orderby COUNT(P.User) Descending
       select new {
         FullName = U.FullName,
         ID = U.Id,
         Records = COUNT(P.User)
       };
```

Comment: Wrong  linq Query

Comment: how to  group by  P and U

Comment: select value ca't used g  object

Answer (score 0):

try code

```
var results = From U In context.AspNetUsers
   Join P In context.PBBuilds On U.Id Equals P.User
   Group new {U,P} By new { P.User, U.FullName } Into g       
   select new {
     FullName = g.FirstOrDefault().U.FullName,
     ID = g.FirstOrDefault().U.Id,
     Records = g.Count()
   }).OrderByDescending(c=>c.Records).ToList();
```